# Integrating Swagger with existing API

Tags: go, swagger, swagger-ui

Is there a way to auto generate only the documentation and client UI to interact with an existing Go service I have already created?

The only problem I have with auto generated code for the API service is because I have two types of supported transports (gRPC and http). I don't want to be confined to an auto generated Swagger server.

Comment: Like this https://github.com/yvasiyarov/swagger?

Comment: @Helen I am shocked when I have been looking around I haven't ran across that.. That's perfect thank you!!

Comment: @Helen it seemed to me that this was an option https://goswagger.io/generate/client.html. The docs just did not go much into depth about generating a client though.

Comment: I used neither so I can't compare.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It can become possible once you have your HTTP service implementation compatible with a tool to collect documentation.

For example you can add magic comments to your code and use https://goswagger.io/generate/spec.html.

Or alternatively you can refactor your http handlers and router setup to match conventions of https://github.com/swaggest/rest and have the spec reflected.